# Need to trigger a script accepting Django form Text field values as parameter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I am very new to Django. I have a script for which i am planning to make a Web APP.
I require some of values to be passed through HTML form action method into my python script. and the script output to be shown in same page or different page.
Example script:

```
a={{get-val1-from form}}
b={{get-val2-from-form}}
def add(a,b):
    return (a+b)
```

My HTML form will look like :

```
<form action="/">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Input Requirements<br></legend>
    <p>
      <label>Value A:<br></label>
      <input type="text" name="val1" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Value B:<br></label>
       <input type="text" name="val2" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="Submit" > Analyze
             </button>
    </p>       
    <p>
      <label>Result : <br></label>
      <textarea id="out_string"> {{out_string}}
      </textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to implement it through Django, kindly let me know the way out using views templates. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

in your **urls.py** define the path where you want to send the input from the user. example

```
from app_name import views
path('answer/', views.answer, name = "ans_url"),
```

Then in your **app_name/views.py** define the view as follows

```
def answer (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_name (request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.cleaned_data['A']
            b = form.cleaned_data['B']
            ans = your_function(a, b)
            return render (request, 'ans_template.html', {'ans' : ans})
    else :
        form = form_name()
    return render (request, 'your_template.html', {'form' : form})

def your_function (a, b):
    #Process
    return (a+b)
```

then in your **your_template.html**, you can define the form as follows

```
<form action="{% url 'ans_url' %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Analyze">
</form>
```

If you are still confused, it will be better to read the documentation once. This is explained very beautifully there.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/